# NodeJS File System sudden UNKNOWN error

Tags: node.js

Few days ago, fs.watch() was still able to work with my path ////networkFolder. But after I restarted the server (hard reset), it gave me an unknown error.

Now for me to check the path I did some troubleshooting, so I used fs.open()

```
fs.open('\\\\networkFolder\\sharedFolder\\p\\a\\t\\h', 'r',  (err, fd) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    fs.close(fd, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

but it gave me an error.

```
Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open '\\networkFolder\sharedFolder\p\a\t\h'
```

Then I used fs.stat() to verify:

```
fs.stat('\\\\networkFolder\\sharedFolder\\p\\a\\t\\h', function(err, stat){
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   } else {
      console.log(stat);
   }
});
```

then the result was:

```
{ Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, stat '\\networkFolder\sharedFolder\p\a\t\h'
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '\\\\networkFolder\\sharedFolder\\p\\a\\t\\h' }
```

From what I remember, I've used net use to setup my network folder but I don't know if that actually help/works in my problem. I did it again but still no luck for me

Please let me know your thoughts regarding the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and figured out that the user account running the node script (Local System in my case) didn't have access to the shared network path. Try running the script as a user that has access to the network share